# What is the difference between ChunkedOutputStream and BufferedOutputStream in Android?

Tags: java, android

What is the difference between `org.apache.http.impl.io.ChunkedOutputStream` and `java.io.BufferedOutputStream`? When do I need one or the other? Does a `ChunkedOutputStream` have an advantage of memory usage over `BufferedOutputStream`?

Comment: unless completely mistaken, BufferedOutputStream is meant for general IO while chunked is primarily for http/https traffic (they both buffer content before flushing it out).

Comment: This question is entirely answered in the Javadoc.

Answer (score 0):

`ChunkedOutputStream` is intended only for writing HTTP responses using the "chunked" transfer encoding. It does not return the same output as `BufferedOutputStream`, which writes the output as is. Therefore, the memory benefits of each are irrelevant unless you're choosing which class to use to write HTTP responses.

Answer (score 0):

ChunkedOutputStream implements HTTP [Chunked Transfer Encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunked_transfer_encoding#Example) which breaks up your message into fragments and inserts length fields before each one.

BufferedOutputStream preserves your message - it just batches up characters to reduce the number of output I/O operations.